# WSO2 EI - < (less than symbol) throwing error in Script mediator (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, wso2, mediator, ei

I have 2 variables stored in properties in WSO2 called date1 and date2, which are both date strings in "YYYY-MM-DD" format. I then have a script that parses the dates and compares to see if date2 is less than date1.

```
<script language ="js">
    var log = mc.getServiceLog();
    var date1 = Date.parse(mc.getProperty('date1'));
    var date2 = Date.parse(mc.getProperty('date2'));
    log.info(date1);
    log.info(date2);
    var date2Before1 = (date2 < date1) ? true : false;
    mc.setProperty("date2Before1", date2Before1);
</script>
```

However, after building my .car file and deploying, I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) in content after '<' (malformed start element?).
```

Not too sure what I'm doing wrong. Could the dates not be getting parsed correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing the Script mediator logic with CDATA element as following

```xml
<script language="js">
    <![CDATA[
        var log = mc.getServiceLog();
        var date1 = Date.parse(mc.getProperty('date1'));
        var date2 = Date.parse(mc.getProperty('date2'));
        log.info(date1);
        log.info(date2);
        var date2Before1 = (date2 < date1 ) ? true : false;
        mc.setProperty("date2Before1", date2Before1);
    ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like that fixed it! Thanks!